# Update contents in DriveItem

Tags: file, graph, onedrive, items

On the DriveItem resource the documentation mentions a "content" property to access the stream of the OneDrive item I have found. However, content is not being returned in the JSON object with the me/drive/items/{item-id} endpoint.  am I missing somthing?

```js
   await this.context.msGraphClientFactory
         .getClient().then(async (client: MSGraphClient):Promise<void> =>{
         await client.api(`me/drive/items/{item-id}`).get().then(foundItem =>{
             console.log(foundItem)
         })
   })
```

returns

```
   @odata.context: ""
   @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl: ""
   eTag: ""
   id: ""
   lastModifiedDateTime: "2020-03-25T14:49:22Z"
   name: ""
   webUrl: ""
   cTag: ""
   size: 141
   createdBy: {user: {…}}
   lastModifiedBy: {user: {…}}
   parentReference:
   driveType: 
   file: {mimeType: "text/plain", hashes: {…}}
   fileSystemInfo: 
   __proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

The binary content will not be return with the item metadata. To get the content you can do a `GET` request against the URL returned in the `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` or add `/content` the end of URL used to fetch the metadata the get the content instead.